# Python scraping - problemas con CSS_SELECTOR

Tags: python, selenium, scraping, spyder

Tengo problemas para obtener la segunda tabla para la fecha `08/01/2010`. Ya tengo la primera tabla con el siguiente código. (Cambiando a la fecha que les indico ni bien se abre la pagina web).

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import math
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import calendar
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pp/EstadisticasSAEEPortal/Paginas/TIActivaTipoCreditoEmpresa.aspx?tip=B")

#Aqui seleccionamos la fecha 10/01/2011 y seguimos

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/stats/TasaDiaria']")))

data=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.APLI_tabla"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df= pd.read_html(data)
```